# MySQLi no inserta en la base de datos y la página queda blanca

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo un formulario que manda los datos al siguiente código, pero cuando lo ejecuto la web se queda blanca. ¿Qué puede estar pasando?

```
<?php
    $id_cancion=$_POST['id_cancion'];
    $nombre_usuario=$_POST['nombre_usuario'];
    $comentario=$_POST['comentario'];

    echo $id_cancion;
    echo $nombre_usuario;
    echo $comentario;

    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','alumno','radius');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL:";
    exit();
    }

    $stmt=$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO peticion (id_cancion, nombre_usuario, comentario) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("iss", $id_cancion,$nombre_usuario,$comentario);
    $stmt->execute();
?>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0)
            {
                echo "Tu peticion de cancion ha sido pedido con exito";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "No ha sido enviada tu peticion";
            }
        ?>
        <p></p>
        <a href="canciones.php">Volver al listado de temas</a>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    $stmt->close();
?>
```

---

Si escribo por pantalla el contenido del $_POST obtengo esto:

```
array(4) { 
   ["id_cancion"]=> string(1) "1" 
   ["nombre"]=> string(6) "sdfsdf" 
   ["comentario"]=> string(6) "sdfsdf" 
   ["enviar"]=> string(15) "Enviar peticion" 
}
```

y cuando ejecuto la página recibo el siguiente error:

> Notice: Undefined index: nombre_usuario in /var/www/html/webradio/peticion2.php on line 8 1sdfsdf Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /var/www/html/webradio/peticion2.php on line 22

Comment: el codigo completo es este:

Answer (score 3):

Buenas,

Las páginas en blanco suelen ser síntoma de algún error en la ejecución del código.

Voy a imaginar que la parte que se ha trastocado al hacer *copia/pega* es esta mas o menos:

```
// ...
$stmt->execute();
?>

<?php
if($stmt->affected_rows > 0)
{
    echo "Tu peticion de cancion ha sido pedido con exito";
}
else
{
    echo "No ha sido enviada tu peticion";
}
?>

    Volver al listado de temas

<?php $stmt->close(); ?>
```

Recomiendo probar dos cosas:

1.- Añadir en la parte superior estas líneas para que te lance los errores en el navegador.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
//...
```

2.- Añade también un `var_dump`para comprobar que `$_POST`trae lo que esperas.

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Si todo va bien debería lanzarte algún error o mostrarte los datos POST recibidos, de forma que te daría pistas para saber que puede estar fallando.

En el caso de que no fuese de ahí, habría que revisar la base de datos, si los campos tienen esos nombres o si la tabla se llama de esa forma.

Prueba y nos cuentas.

Saludos,

---

**EDITO por el comentario realizado.**

El error está en que no coincide lo que recibes con lo que declaras.
La key que recibes es `nombre`:

```
["nombre"]=> string(6) "sdfsdf"
```

Y la key que estás declarando es `nombre_usuario`:

```
$nombre_usuario=$_POST['nombre_usuario'];
```

Cuando debería ser:

```
$nombre_usuario=$_POST['nombre'];
```

---

**EDICION 2ª**

Sobre lo comentado abajo de probarlo en un Script limpio con datos estáticos, me refería a algo así:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$id_cancion     = 2;
$nombre_usuario = 'Usuario';
$comentario     = 'Comentario';

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'alumno', 'radius');
var_dump(mysqli_connect_errno());

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO peticion (id_cancion, nombre_usuario, comentario) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("iss", $id_cancion, $nombre_usuario, $comentario);
$stmt->execute();
var_dump($stmt->affected_rows);
$stmt->close();
?>
```

Lo he probado con los datos que has facilitado. Debería darte una salida en el navegador así:

```
int 0
int 1
```

Si toda la información facilitada es correcta, el script estaría bien y funcionando. Si falla, habría que irse a revisar la base de datos.

**Añado el esquema básico de la tabla**

```
CREATE TABLE peticion
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_cancion INT,
    nombre_usuario VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    comentario VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Me devuelve esto:
array(4) { ["id_cancion"]=> string(1) "1" ["nombre"]=> string(6) "sdfsdf" ["comentario"]=> string(6) "sdfsdf" ["enviar"]=> string(15) "Enviar peticion" }
Notice: Undefined index: nombre_usuario in /var/www/html/webradio/peticion2.php on line 8
1sdfsdf
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /var/www/html/webradio/peticion2.php on line 22

Comment: Respuesta editada...

Comment: Buena respuesta y buen seguimiento

Comment: Ya hice los cambios de quitar las comillas y cambiar el nombre de la variable pero sigo con un error de bind_param

Comment: Comprueba que la tabla y los campos está correctamente definidos: tabla: peticion / Campos: id_cancion, nombre_usuario, comentario. Hay algo que no encaja y sigue lanzando el error.

Comment: La tabla es esta:
 # Nombre Tipo Cotejamiento Atributos Nulo Predeterminado Extra Acción
 1 id int(11)   No  Ninguna AUTO_INCREMENT Cambiar Cambiar Eliminar Eliminar 

    Más

 2 comentario varchar(45) latin1_swedish_ci  Sí  NULL  Cambiar Cambiar Eliminar Eliminar 

    Más

 3 nombre_usuario varchar(45) latin1_swedish_ci  No  Ninguna  Cambiar Cambiar Eliminar Eliminar 

    Más

 4 fecha_hora datetime   No  Ninguna  Cambiar Cambiar Eliminar Eliminar 

    Más

 5 id_cancion int(11)   No  Ninguna  Cambiar Cambiar Eliminar Eliminar 

    Más

Comment: Elimine el campo de la fecha ahora hay los 3 del formulario mas el identificador que es auto_increment.

Comment: Saúl, creo que tienes que repasar todos los nombres tanto de las variables que recibes, como los de la base de datos, como los de la `query`. El error de `bind_param` se lanza si hay algún error por que no coincide. Por que si fuese un campo indicado como `unique` y se repitiese la inserción o fuese problema de la longitud de caracteres (por poner un ejemplo) simplemente te saldría el mensaje del `else` "No ha sido enviada tu petición", pero no un error `bind_param`.

Comment: Comprobe los tipos y datos y nombres y los tengo bien sigo sin saber por que falla de todas maneras tendra que ver con el id de la peticion que no lo tengo en el formulario pero es la clave primaria y lo tengo auto increment?

Comment: En teoría no. Un `auto increment`, como su propio nombre indica incrementa su valor automáticamente por cada registro que introduces sin tener que manipularlo directamente. Dudo que sea ese el error. Para ir descartando, inténtalo con un script limpio y datos estáticos sin que provengan de un formulario. Solo la consulta con los datos de entrada y verifica la respuesta a ver que sale.

Comment: Despues de añadir esto y comentario los $_POST:
 $id_cancion=1;
 $nombre_usuario='prueba';
 $comentario='no hay';
el resultado que obtengo es este:
array(0) { } 1pruebano hay
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /var/www/html/webradio/peticion2.php on line 26

Comment: Con tu codigo obtengo este error:
int(0)
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /var/www/html/webradio/peticion3.php on line 13

Comment: el id_cancion es int(11) y los otros dos varchar(45)

Comment: Saúl, he añadido el esquema básico de la tabla. Con esos datos debería funcionar sin problemas. Si hay un error está en la base de datos.

Comment: Y que tipo de error puede ser?? Vamos no se que hacer ahora mismo

Comment: Pues así con la información que se ha intercambiado, no sabría decirte. Yo en tu caso empezaría como se arreglan las averías... probando desde lo más básico hasta llegar a localizar el error. Crea una tabla de uso temporal con dos campos, `id` y `nombre`, que permitan `null` y prueba a hacer una inserción. ¿Funciona? Cambias php y cambias base de datos... Así vas aumentando poco a poco buscando la funcionalidad que tienes actualmente. En alguno de los cambios vas a encontrarte el error. A veces es una tontería, pero cuando no es tan evidente, toca que hacerlo así.

Comment: Voy a intentar cargarme la tabla y volver a hacerla a ver si de esta manera funciona por que sino... la base es InnoDB pero no se si habra problema por eso voy a hacerla como antes el id int(11) los demas varchar(45) y la clave foranea id_cancion int(11) asi no deberia dar problemas no???

Comment: InnoDB no tiene por que darte problemas. Lo que si, asegúrate cuando llegues a la parte de asociar los `id_cancion` con tabla correspondiente, que el id que insertas esté ya disponible en la tabla de canciones.

Comment: Lo está es el id 1 y existe me come esto es lo que necesito para terminar el proyecto fin de ciclo

Answer (score 1):

El fallo lo tienes en la declaración de las variables

```
 $id_cancion=$_POST['id_cancion'];
 $nombre_usuario=$_POST['nombre_usuario'];**
 $comentario=$_POST['comentario']
```

Mas o menos tú has dado la respuesta en la pregunta al poner el post que recibes

```
array(4) { 
 ["id_cancion"]=> string(1) "1" 
 ["nombre"]=> string(6) "sdfsdf"** 
 ["comentario"]=> string(6) "sdfsdf" 
 ["enviar"]=> string(15) "Enviar peticion" 
}
```

Si te fijas, en el post, la variable se llama nombre, pero luego quieres cargar nombre:usuario, de ahí que te muestre el error.

Answer (score 0):

Cordial Saludo.

1. Tu primer error es que estas llamando a un indexe que no existe en tu arreglo $_POST. Cambiar:

> ```
> $id_cancion=$_POST['id_cancion'];
> $nombre_usuario=$_POST['nombre_usuario'];
> $comentario=$_POST['comentario'];
> ```

Por

```
$id_cancion=$_POST['id_cancion'];
$nombre_usuario=$_POST['nombre'];
$comentario=$_POST['comentario'];
```

2. La utilización de la función **bind_param** no funciona por que al ejecutar la función `$mysqli->prepare` retorno error y no un objeto. Te recomiendo colocar el codigo en un IF en caso que falle. Ej:

   if ($stmt=$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO peticion (id_cancion, nombre_usuario, comentario) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
       ) {
   }

Por favor adiciona la estructura de la tabla.